# Github blog image upload fail (Markdown path)

Tags: github, markdown, blogs

I am making a blog with Github. I forked from someone else's and only edited the words. So I don't really have basic knowledge of web programming.

The problem is the path doesn't go to the right page when I attach the picture. It kept shows an error.
I figured out why the error shows up, but I can't find how to solve this problem.

Path (which should be worked):
https://github.com/babydoyaji/babydoyaji.github.io/blob/master/assets/img/TIL210105/0105_1.png

What I put:

```
![testing](../assets/img/TIL210105/0105_1.png)
```

I also put this. But this doesn't work too.

```
![testing](.../assets/img/TIL210105/0105_1.png)
```

This page shows up. (/blog path should not exist):
https://github.com/babydoyaji/babydoyaji.github.io/blob/master/blog/assets/img/TIL210105/0105_1.png

The result :
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UaVEX.png)

I can't find how to take off that **/blog** from the path.

The one solution I am thinking is moving the img folder inside the blog folder, but I don't want to put folders like that.

If anyone knows how to remove the /blog from the path with markdown code, please help me.

Thank you.